# Why does my kernel thread execute only once?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

[following this post](http://tuxthink.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/kernel-thread-creation-1.html) I have implemented in my kernel module:

```
static int val = 1;
static char thread_name[128] = "my thread name";
```

in  the init:

```
thread1 = kthread_run(thread_fn, &val, thread_name);
```

and this is the function

```
int thread_fn(void *data)
{
    unsigned long j0,j1;
    int delay = 60*HZ;
    j0 = jiffies; 
    j1 = j0 + delay; 

    printk(KERN_INFO "here");

    while (time_before(jiffies, j1)) 
        schedule();
    return 1;
}
```

Why does this execute only 1 time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer to [How to stop Linux kernel threads on rmmod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280693/kernel-thread-implementation), and some of my own poking around, I suspect that there are two possible causes:

1. Your function returns.
2. Your thread state is `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, so a call to `schedule()` will never return.

If you wrap the body in a `while (! kthread_should_stop() )` loop, and make sure that your task is in a `TASK_RUNNING` state before a call to `schedule()`, then it will keep running:

```
int thread_fn(void *data)
{
    unsigned long j1;
    int delay = 5*HZ;  /* use a 5-second delay instead of a 60-sec one */

    int count = 0;
    while (! kthread_should_stop() ) {
        j1 = jiffies + delay; 

        printk(KERN_INFO "here %d\n", ++count);

        while (time_before(jiffies, j1)) {
            set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
            schedule();
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @0x90: I found that it would work after adding a call to set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING) before the call to schedule().

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of any thread. If you want a cyclical behaviour, you need a loop in `thread_fn`.
Here is a nice documentation for kernel threads: https://prof.hti.bfh.ch/myf1/adv-linux/courseNotes/kthread-intro-1.2.pdf